# Apply the mean value theorem to find $x_0$ with $\varphi(g(b))-\varphi(g(a))=\varphi'(g(x_0))(g(b)-g(a))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

Let $\varphi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be continuously differentiable and $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ be continuous. Are we able to show that $$\varphi(g(b))-\varphi(g(a))=\varphi'(g(x_0))(g(b)-g(a))\tag1$$ for some $x_0\in[a,b]$? This claim is made in the [proof of Theorem 3.70 of PDE and Martingale Methods in Option Pricing](https://books.google.com/books?id=g0LlXe5iN3AC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=%22by+the+mean+value+theorem+and+the+continuity+of%22+%22pascucci%22&source=bl&ots=R00k386iH2&sig=ACfU3U2Ow2Abs4UVm9OS12s5_lz_3je6XQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE2aHXn4f1AhWbSfEDHdIEAP0Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22by%20the%20mean%20value%20theorem%20and%20the%20continuity%20of%22%20%22pascucci%22&f=false) and it is stated that it would follow from the mean value theorem. However, it's obviously *not* an immediate application of the mean value theorem.

So, how do we obtain it?

I first thought we might need to use that $I:=g([a,b])$ is again a closed interval and then apply the mean value theorem to the restriction of $\varphi$ to $I$. However, this only yields the existence of $x_0\in I$ with $\varphi'(x_0)=\frac{\varphi(\max I)-\varphi(\min I)}{\max I-\min I}$, which is obviously not the same as $(1)$ (unless $g$ is nondecreasing, which is not assumed in the reference).

---

I'd also be interested in a generalization of the same claim to the case when $\varphi:E\to F$ and $g:[a,b]\to E$ for some $\Bbb R$-Banach spaces $E$ and $F$. In this case, there should be some kind of mean-value inequality yielding the existence of $x_0\in[a,b]$ with $$\left\|\varphi(g(b))-\varphi(g(a))\right\|_F\le\left\|{\rm D}\varphi(g(x_0))(g(b)-g(a))\right\|_F\tag2$$ or at least $$\left\|\varphi(g(b))-\varphi(g(a))\right\|_F\le\left\|{\rm D}\varphi(g(x_0))\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E,\:F)}\left\|g(b)-g(a)\right\|_E\tag3.$$

Comment: So I followed the link you provided. They assume that $\varphi$ is not just differentiable, but that $\varphi$ is continuously differentiable.  You need the continuity of the derivative and the fact that you are working on a compact space to make the result true.

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Thank you for your comment. Assuming that $\varphi$ is continuously differentiable is not a problem. I've added this assumption to the question. But which space do you think we need to assume to be compact? In the generalization that I've described at the end of the question, the image $g([a,b])$ is still a compact subset of $E$. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Let $J$ be the closed interval from $g(a)$ to $g(b)$ i.e $J:=[g(a),g(b)]$ if $g(a)\leq g(b)$ and $J:=[g(b),g(a)]$ else. Continuity of $\varphi$ on $J$ and differentiability on the interior allows you to use the mean-value theorem as usual to show there exists $t_0\in J$ such that $\phi(g(b))-\phi(g(a))=\phi'(t_0)\cdot [g(b)-g(a)]$. The intermediate value theorem applied to $g$ now tells you $t_0=g(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in [a,b]$.

So, this doesn't require continuous differentiability of $\varphi$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Hm, but why should this yield $(1)$? As I wrote in the question, this should only yield a $x_0\in J$ with $\varphi'(x_0)=\frac{\varphi(\max J)-\varphi(\min J)}{\max J-\min J}$

Comment: @0xbadf00d right, and can you tell me what is $\max J$ and $\min J$ (also, it's better to write things out in the multiplied version, to avoid the trivial technical issue of dividing by $0$)?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Well, $\min J=\operatorname{argmin}_{t\in J}g(t)$, which doesn't need to be $g(a)$, unless $g$ is nondecreasing.

Comment: No. Look at my definition of $J$ again. My $J$ is not what you're calling $I$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, sorry, you're right. I guess this should work using the intermediate value theorem as you described. But does the same thing generalize to the Banach space case? I guess we should be able to do the same, using the mean value inequality in place of the mean-value theorem. Do you agree?

Comment: No, the mean-value inequality gives a bound using the operator norm of $D \phi$ on the line-sgement joining two given points: $\|\phi(x)-\phi(y)\|\leq \left(\sup\limits_{t\in [0,1]}\|D\phi_{tx+(1-t)y}\|\right)\cdot \|x-y\|$. This is too crude of a bound to get what you're asking for in (2). Sure, in the case of continuously differentiable $\phi$ the supremum is actually attained, but this is still too crude of a bound.

Comment: @peek-a-boo This might be enough for what I'm trying to achieve (see $(3)$ in my edit). As you may already have guessed, I'm looking for a generalization of the actual theorem in the reference to the Banach space case. I've asked a separate question for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4343855/47771. Maybe you can take a look!

Answer (score 1):

If $g(a)=g(b)$, $LHS=RHS=0$ for any choice of $x_{0}\in[a,b]$.
Suppose that $g(a)\neq g(b)$. If $g(a)<g(b)$, we apply Mean-Value
Theorem on $\varphi\mid_{[g(a),g(b)]}$ (the restriction of $\varphi$
on $[g(a),g(b)]$), there exists $\xi\in(g(a),g(b))$ such that $\varphi(g(b))-\varphi(g(a))=\varphi'(\xi)\left[g(b)-g(a)\right]$.
Since $g$ is continuous, by Intermediate Value Theorem, we can choose
$x_{0}\in(a,b)$ such that $g(x_{0})=\xi$. That is, $\varphi(g(b))-\varphi(g(a))=\varphi'(g(x_{0}))\left[g(b)-g(a)\right]$.

The case that $g(a)>g(b)$ can be treated similarly.

Comment: It seems that the proof is elementary. Moreover, we do not require that $\varphi$ is continuously differentiable. That $\varphi$ is differentiable is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you've got an idea for the general case as well?